# Python - Apply the formatting of an existing workbook to another workbook

Tags: python, excel, excel-2007, xlwt, openpyxl

I am relatively new to coding in Python, and here is my problem:
 1- When I update data of an existing .xlsx file (using openpyxl), the outcome is a .xlsx that looses all the previous formatting. I've also tried with .xls (using xlwt and xlrd), but nothing changed.
 2- So, I decided to keep this unformatted outcome file and apply all the formatting of a template .xls(x) file.

Is there an straight forward way to preserve the formatting at the step 1? if not, how can I implement step 2?

P.S: I've tried to handle styles with xlutils.styles... but I didn't manage to...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Right now formatting support for the Python packages that work directly with Excel files (without Excel itself) is quite weak.  If you will be doing this on a machine with Excel on it, your best bet right now (if you want to stick to Python) is to use something like `pywin32` or `pywinauto`. If you're open to non-Python options, VBScript is actually not too bad, and it's already included on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the format of a cell with xlrd and set it as the style of a cell you're writing in xlwt. The cell's `xf_index` attribute is an instance of the XFStyle object and can be dumped directly into the style argument of a `write` method, like so:

```
import xlwt,xlrd
readbook = xlrd.open_workbook('book.xls', formatting_info=True)
readsheet = readbook.sheet_by_index(0)
cell = sheet.cell(0,0)
writebook = xlwt.Workbook()
writesheet = writebook.add_sheet('sheet1')
writesheet.write(0,0,'First Cell', cell.xf_index)
```

From there you can either iterate to match each cell's format or you can write each format to rows or columns, as shown here: https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/xlwt/examples/row_styles.py